# a small issue in using exception handling in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

The below given simple exception program is giving Unhandled Exception "Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0012fe94..". I am getting this error immediately after the function excep() is returned.
Please can anyone tell why this error is coming here. Also it will be helpful if all the possible mistakes in this code were explained/analysed. I am learning to code better.

I am using Visual C++ 2005.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int excep(int);

   throw excep(20);

   return 0;
}

int excep(int e)
{

    cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @phresnel - Care to explain ?

Comment: @phresnel - Now you are being quite vague. You don't explain what you mean and then hijack the subject. Better be a bit sane when accusing people. And make your points before accusing others. No need to be a daft. And this is a comment section not an answer section. A book would have been more useful for him, when you say the OP thinks he is catching an exception, And when did exclamation marks became rude ?

Comment: @phresnel: I only see one person in these comments overusing exclamation marks. And I'd say that if you think your exception is being caught, being told that it isn't is a pretty damn good first step in correcting the problem. Also, could you please take that "holier than thou" attitude and stick it where the sun doesn't shine? You could just say what you wanted to say without the "unlike you" bullshit.

Comment: oh, may I know why the question got -1 flag

Comment: @DumbCoder: Yes. Only, which book? As for exclamation marks: I find a single one should be enough. More than  one will be read like shouting, commanding, ranting, inveighing, or just being childish. While this is what I felt since I can read, some articles confirm it: http://communicationskillsblog.communicaid.com/writing-skills/effective-business-writing-the-exclamation-mark/ , http://www.mitsol.net/Default.aspx/Solutions/Mail-Solutions/Effective-Use-Of-Email/pageId_107 (search for exclamation marks) , http://dan.hersam.com/opinions/exclamation.html .

Comment: +1 just to compensate the downvote, Asking a pretty basic question or having a wrong understanding should not be the basis for downvoting a question.

Comment: @DumbCoder (offline edit + repost): Put less bluntly: You just tell the asker that his exceptions isn't caught. That doesn't help him because he thinks he is catching it already. Then you are overusing exclamation marks, making your comment sound even more rude.

Comment: +1 compensation. This site is not for the highly skilled only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
throw excep(20);
```

`excep(20)` is called first, whose return value is then thrown, i.e. you throw an integer. It is roughly equivalent to:

```
const int i = excep(20);
throw i;
```

To get you an idea how exception-snytax looks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   try {
       // do something
       throw std::runtime_error("test");
   } catch (const std::exception &e) {
       std::cout << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
}
```

In practive: **NEVER** throw anything that is not derived from `std::exception`.

Proposed Readings:

- Introductory book on C++ (search stackoverflow for this)
- [C++ FAQ on Exception Handling](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html)
- "Exceptional C++" (for advanced C++ users)

Comment: Thanks phresnel, i got the point i missed. thanks for for ur reference

Answer (score 3):

If you try to learn exception throwing/handling your code contains an error.
function excep must handle object that was thrown not to be thrown itself.
your code must be rewritten as follows:

```
using namespace std;
int excep(int e) 
{ 
       cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << endl; 
       return 0;
}
int main () 
{ 
     int excep(int);
     try
     { // <--------- Begin of try block. required part of the exception handling
         throw 20;
     }
     catch (const int &errCode) // <------- we are catching only ints
     {
             excep(errCode); // Function that handles exception
     }

     return 0; 
}
```

It is good design not to throw int variables, but type that inherites std::exception. But this is more advanced exception using knowledge

Answer (score 3):

What did you expect to happen?

You call a function which prints out "An exception occurred", plus the other text, and then you throw the resulting value as an exception, which you never catch, so the program reports than an uncaught exception was thrown. Which is true, because that's exactly what you just did.

The entire point in exceptions is that when you throw an exception, it will propagate out through the program, until it is either handled, or it reaches the top level and terminates the program. You don't handle the exception, so it terminates the program.

If you want to handle an exception, you need to wrap the throwing code in a `try` block, followed by a `catch`, as in:

```
try {
    throw excep(20);
}
catch (int ex) {
   // do something about the exception
}
```

Comment: That does not really help the confused asker. The problem is not an uncaught exception, but that he got the syntax wrong.

Comment: @phresnel - Are you a mind reader or something ? Where does the OP ask for correcting his syntax ?

Comment: @phresnel: you know, first of all, I'm pretty amazed at your mind-reading abilities. Especially considering that the OP literally *had* no syntax for catching the exception, I find it hard to agree with the statement that "he merely got the syntax wrong". The problem is that he threw an exception which he didn't catch. The *solution* is to understand how exception handling works. And correct me if I'm wrong, but I do believe that my answer also illustrates the syntax, so I'm not even sure what you're complaining about.

Comment: @DumbCoder (CC @Jalf): _He/Her did not_, which is exactly the problem; it somewhat implies the OP assumes something for correct and is looking for a bug at some othogonal topic. The source code imho self-documents that `execp()` is ought to be an exception handler: `An exception occurred. Exception Nr.`. I doubt that `execp` was meant to be a "decorator", and I read the code as being written by a yet unexperienced C++ programmer.

Comment: Thanks jalf, i tried this way as i remember i read long back that the compiler will rewrite the code into try catch blocks, so i just experimented, i thought its working fine but looking why the memory exception is coming for an int.. Now i got i am wrong in assumption.